# DELETE with HTTP_NO_CONTENT/204 not return the response

Tags: php, json, rest, codeigniter, postman

I try to make restful with the help of Codeigniter and [chriskacerguis/codeigniter-rest](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) library

I made a feature to delete data and if it was successful it will send status 204 and response message,

so the problem is, that not return response message if with status 204 but if followed by status 200, and etc, it works properly

I test it with Postman,
and yes of course i test it on body menu

here the code :

```
 public function index_delete()
    {
        $id = $this->delete('id');
        if ($id === null) {
            //---- working fine return the response----
            $this->response([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Provide an id!'
            ], REST_Controller_Definitions::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            if ($this->employee->deleteEmployee($id) > 0) { 
              //----working, but not return the response----
                 $this->response([
                   'status' => true,
                   'id' => $id,
                   'message' => 'Successfully Deleted'
                ], REST_Controller_Definitions::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
             } else {
               //---- working fine return the response---
               $this->response([
                  'status' => false,
                  'message' => 'Id is not exits!'
                ], REST_Controller_Definitions::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); 
             }
         }
     }
```

but if I change the status `HTTP_NO_CONTENT` to `HTTP_OK` or `HTTP_BAD_REQUEST` or etc it working properly

and I've also tried it this way, like in `Example.php` on `chriskacerguis-restserver` but i got nothing

```
$message = [
             'status' => true,
             'id' => $id,
             'message' => 'Deleted'
            ];
$this->set_response($message, REST_Controller_Definitions::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
```

and this is my method :

```
public function deleteEmployee($id)
{

  $this->db->delete('employees', ['id' => $id]);
  return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

so the problem is in my code, the library, or postman software?

Answer (score -1):

A 204 means "no content". You can't send any response data back with a 204.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has
> successfully fulfilled the request and **that there is no additional
> content to send in the response payload body**.  Metadata in the
> response header fields refer to the target resource and its selected
> representation after the requested action was applied.

> ...

> The server assumes that **the user agent will provide
> some indication of the success to its user**, in accord with its own
> interface, and apply any new or updated metadata in the response to
> its active representation.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5

> The 204 response **MUST NOT include a message-body**, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: really? some time ago I had seen a case like this and returned a response, I just want to inform the requester that the data was deleted successfully by sending a response in the form of json containing a message

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung A 204 *already* means "that was successful". If you want to send data back, send a 200 instead.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the quote from 2616 with the updated version from RFC 7231.